# Force Google Cloud Document AI to use British date format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am using document-ai to parse invoices via their javascript API. The dates may sometimes get picked up correctly, but sometimes it assumes them to be American `MM/DD/YYYY` rather than the British `DD/MM/YYYY`, a format which applies to all the invoices we're parsing. This is the "normalized value" (translated to `YYYY-MM-DD`) rather than the plain text, which will be correct for our region.

Is there any way to give parameters to document-ai to say "assume British" for these kinds of values? Equally it would be good to be able to train the AI personally for areas it picks up the wrong values. It's very hit and miss.

I assume it's not something that can be controlled, but if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Hi, GCP support here. We would like to take a look at the invoices you are parsing. [Can you raise a confidential thread in the issue tracker (referencing this question, as stated in the template) with some example invoices where the date format is 'YYYY-DD-MM'?](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1132255&template=1639132)  After you've created the thread, please share the issue ID here, so we can follow up. Note that issues in that component will only be accessible for you and GCP support.

Comment: I think the Google Cloud Document AI just returns the **string** that is OCR read on the document without any formatting rules.
At least that's what it does is the invoice-parser processor. Which processor are you using?
For the date interpretation, I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72559354/get-date-values-day-month-year-from-date-string-random-format