# Get date values DAY MONTH YEAR from date string (random format)

Tags: date, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I want to get the date values (day, month, year) from a date string that can be in any common date format (metric, retard, string, number, German, English...)

Some examples are:

- "12. Mai 2022"
- "5/12/22"
- "May 12, 2022"
- "05.05.22"
- "12.5.2022"

Solutions can be Code (JS,PHP,Python), RegEx or (preferred) **an API that does this**. A 95% solution is fine.

Background: We are using the [Google Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs) for scanning invoices, and want to put the date from the invoices into sheets, using a no code solution (Integromat / make.com). Unfortunately, the Document AI [only returns the date field as a string](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list?hl=en_US#processor_invoice-processor), not as a date value.

Comment: Stack overflow is oriented to provided solutions to coding challenges and isn't suited to recommendations for solutions or for code-writing. Your sample data highlights an issue. In the US, `5/12/22` is May 12th but for most of the rest of the World, this is interpreted as 5th December. Same with `05.05.22` and `12.5.2022`. These dates are all ambiguous without additional context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @DazWilkin! Yes, I see the problem with US vs. UK format. That is why I said it would be OK if not all cases are interpreted correctly.
What I don't really understand is your first sentence. I assume you want to say that Stack overflow is more for already existing code that is to be discussed? If so, what would be the appropriate place to ask a question like this?

Comment: Have a look at [If you question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the link @DazWilkin - but actually, I do not see that this question would not fit here from the information given there. But still - would you recommend posting it on Superuser then?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using certain Specialized Processors, like the Invoice Parser, then you should be able to use [EKG Enrichment & Normalization](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/ekg-enrichment) to get the date in a standard string format, or as structured data.

You can access this in the [`normalizedValue`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#normalizedvalue) field in the `Document` object. This How-to Guide [Handling the Processing Response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#fields_and_normalized_values) describes the process and the [Specialized Processors Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-specialized-processors-python) has some code samples for how to do this.

Comment: Thank you @Holt Skinner!
As I understand, the EKG is only used for the supplier fields (supplier_address, supplier_name, supplier_phone) in the invoice parser.
In the example https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#fields_and_normalized_values the invoice_date has a key called 'normalizedValue', but in my API answers, 'normalizedValue' is missing.
In the documentation it says: "For certain fields, the processor also normalizes the value. In this example, the date has been normalized from 2020/01/01 to 2020-01-01."
Is there a way to activate / force that for invoice_date?

Comment: The documentation could probably be improved here, but the date fields should have normalization applied, even if they don't use EKG enrichment.

The normalizedValue should be populated automatically if it was able to be parsed. Be sure that you're using the V1 API through REST/Client Libraries. You can also try uploading a test document to the Cloud Console to see if the normalized Dates appear with the Google "G".